# Convert ARGB to RGBA format

Tags: javascript, colors, rgba, argb

I have an 8-bit hex decimal which is in `aarrggbb` format. I need methods to convert this to `rrggbbaa` format and vise versa. For eg

**ARGB format**

`#FFFF2323`

What i need is **RGBA format**

`#FF2323FF`

Comment: so, you have a string #FFFF2323? you want `'#FFFF2323'.replace(/#(..)(......)/, '#$2$1')`

Comment: @JaromandaX Very elegant solution. Please make it an answer to the question :-)

Comment: where did that non regex answer go! It was fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're dealing with a string `#FF123456`

```js
let x = '#FF123456';
console.log(x.replace(/#(..)(......)/, '#$2$1'));
```

If, however, x is a number, 0xFF123456 -

```js
let x = 0xFF123456
console.log(`#${(x & 0x0FFFFFF).toString(16).padStart(6, '0')}${(x >>> 24).toString(16).padStart(2, '0')}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is move a[1] and a[2] to the end

`var a = "#AABBCCDD";`

`var b = "#"+a.slice(3,9)+a[1]+a[2];`

Comment: I like yours better :p